# How to save new data into a push id generated from previous activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P2bD.png)

Hi guys, I'm new to firebase. Hopefully, some expert or guru in Firebase could give me help in solving this problem. Thank you!

Plan to save data in **yellow highlight** to **blue highlight**

Final Result as ***duration, info, time, matricno, password under one push id***

**First Activity Code (Attempt action with blue highlight)**

```
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

DatabaseReference myRef = db.getReference("Class Information");

String key = myRef.push().getKey();

myRef.child(uid).child("Student Attend").child(key).setValue(classInformation);
```

**Second Activity Code (Attempt action with yellow highlight)**

```
DatabaseReference myRef = abRef.push();

String key = myRef.push().getKey();

DatabaseReference abRef = myRef.child(uid).child("Student Attend").child(key);

abRef.setValue(student);
```

Comment: "abRef.setValue(student);" is student model class or map?@Jodan

Comment: it is a model class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you are using DatabaseReference's [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()) method using:

```
String key = myRef.push().getKey();
```

A brand new random key is generated. If you want to use the key that is generated in your first activity, in the second activity, you should [send it through an Intent or a Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application) and **not** generate it again.

Comment: hi @AlexMamo do you mind to review on my latest question? as i have doubt on it

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.